# How to calculate balanced cluster of 1-d data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

Im aware of many other questions here on asking what clustering algorithms are usable for 1-d data, but my question is how to calculate **balanced** clusters?

E.g. I have a list

```
l = [46, 48, 68, 46, 48, 68, 63, 62, 63, 63, 69, 54, 64, 61, 66, 54, 64, 67, 46, 48]
```

and I know I need 3 clusters. But using KMeans clustering would give me

```
l = np.array(l, dtype=np.int16)
l = np.expand_dims(l, axis=1)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
labels = kmeans.fit_predict(l)
print(labels)
> array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Obviously the clustering is totally imbalanced:

```
print(np.unique(labels, return_counts=True))
> (array([0, 1, 2]), array([ 6, 12,  2], dtype=int64))
```

So, is there a way to cluster 1-d data in Python and having a more or less **balanced** clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by dividing your array in 3 quantiles. In `pandas` you can use `qcut` from `pandas` like in the example below.

```
l = [46, 48, 68, 46, 48, 68, 63, 62, 63, 63, 69, 54, 64, 61, 66, 54, 64, 67, 46, 48]

a = pd.qcut(l, 3, labels=[0, 1, 2])
print(a.to_numpy())
[0 0 2 0 0 2 1 1 1 1 2 0 2 1 2 0 2 2 0 0]
```

Or you can just use `np.quantile` from numpy to manually calculate the quantile values which then could use to assign cluster labels on new observations.

```
l = np.array([46, 48, 68, 46, 48, 68, 63, 62, 63, 63, 69, 54, 64, 61, 66, 54, 64, 67, 46, 48])

lower_q = np.quantile(l, 1/3)
upper_q = np.quantile(l, 2/3)

cl = []
for v in l:
    if v <= lower_q:
        cl.append(0)
    elif v > lower_q and v <= upper_q:
        cl.append(1)
    else: 
        cl.append(2)

cl = np.array(cl)
print(cl)
```